# Proper way to stop Akka Streams on condition

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have been successfully using [FileIO](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.140568374.588201913.1464855311#akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO$) to stream the contents of a file, compute some transformations for each line and aggregate/reduce the results.

Now I have a pretty specific use case, where I would like to stop the stream when a condition is reached, so that it is not necessary to read the whole file but the process finishes as soon as possible. What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: If the condition is based on the stream content, `Source.takewhile` (http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.8/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@takeWhile(p:Out=>Boolean):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]) should work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## If the stop condition is "on the outside of the stream"

There is a advanced building-block called `KillSwitch` that you could use to do this: http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.7/akka/stream/KillSwitches.html The stream would get shut down once the kill switch is notified.

It has methods like `abort(reason)` / `shutdown` etc, see here for it's API: http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.7/akka/stream/SharedKillSwitch.html

Reference documentation is here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#kill-switch-scala

Example usage would be:

```
val countingSrc = Source(Stream.from(1)).delay(1.second,
    DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure)
val lastSnk = Sink.last[Int]

val (killSwitch, last) = countingSrc
  .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
  .toMat(lastSnk)(Keep.both)
  .run()

doSomethingElse()

killSwitch.shutdown()

Await.result(last, 1.second) shouldBe 2
```

---

## If the stop condition is inside the stream

You can use `takeWhile` to express any condition really, though sometimes `take` or `limit` may be also enough "take 10 lnes".

If your logic is very advanced, you could build a special stage that handles that special logic using `statefulMapConcat` that allows to express literally anything - so you could complete the stream whenever you want to "from the inside".

Comment: What if I need to switch on and off for the continuously stream so that my reduce function call emits the aggregated (grouped) data to Sink? Can I use takeWhile(p) , and swithc p true and false?