# Akka Streams `groupBy` capacity change on SubFlow completion?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

When using `groupBy` in a stream flow definition with some max capacity of `n`:

```
source.groupBy(Int.MaxValue, _.key).to(Sink.actorRef)
```

If I hook up the subflows that result to say, an Actor sink, and purposefully cause the subflows to terminate on some message, will that free up the `groupBy` capacity? Will it go from `n` to `n-1` back to `n` if a subflow is ended by the sink? Is this a viable way to set up a dynamic-ish graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding how `groupBy` works in general: **yes**, the maxSubstreams capacity is dynamic, i.e. it represents the maximum number of **active substreams**.

The `GroupBy` stage keeps a reference of each subflow in its internal state, and this is removed whenever that specific subflow completes.

With regards to your specific example, I don't think there is a way to make sure that "a subflow is ended by the sink". This is because by using `to(Sink.actorRef)` after a `groupBy` all the flows are going to feed one single actor.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Is there, then, a recommended way to gracefully shut down a subflow?

Comment: Stumbled across this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325210/proper-way-to-stop-akka-streams-on-condition; looks like I may be able to achieve what I want using `takeWhile` / `statefulMapconcat`